# Abort file import operation in c#

Tags: c#, file, upload

I want to implement abort/cancel file import operation in c#.
I am using below code to achieve this -

```
CancellationTokenSource ctokensource;
            if (_importtasks.TryGetValue(Convert.ToInt32(jobHistoryRecno), out ctokensource))
                ctokensource.Cancel();
```

Even though, it execute above function successfully, It fails to cancel the task. still import is keep going.

Could you please help me how to achieve abort/cancel functionality on file import.

Regards
Rajiv Kumar

Answer (score 0):

`Cancel` just informs attached token (which you can get with [CancellationTokenSource.Token](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.token%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property) about cancellation. You should cancel your operation manually by  either checking [CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.iscancellationrequested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or calling [CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()](http://CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested), the second method should be used if operation is wrapped with `Task`. Also you can register the necessary callback with [CancellationToken.Register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321635%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method, which will be executed when cancellation requested.